# Бинарное дерево и красно-черное дерево

Tags: структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, в чем разница между красно-черным деревом и бинарным деревом? Вижу разницу только в том, что красно-черное дерево промаркировано цветом, только не понятно для чего. Чтобы перестраивать дерево когда оно становится несбалансированным? Разве нельзя сделать такое же и в бинарном дереве без маркировки? Я же могу так же перестроить.

Comment: Маркировка цветом проводится по таким правилам, что при вставке/удалении узла можно быстро определить, что требуется перебалансировка дерева, при этом отнюдь не каждая операция с rb-tree может требовать новой балансировки.

Comment: Как этот цвет может помочь определить что нужна перебалансировка

Comment: Прочтите внимательно разделы [Свойства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.A1.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0) и [Вставка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.92.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0) в [вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Comment: и все рано не понимаю для чего цвета, цвета то все равно меняются при поворотах.

Comment: Правильно. Они меняются вместе с перебалансировкой дерева таким образом, чтобы отражать тот факт, что дерево уже снова сбалансировано. Мы узнаем, например при вставке, что она приводит к разбалансировке дерева, когда смотрим на цвета. Затем мы вращаем поддеревья и меняем цвета так, чтобы он соответствовали свойствам сбалансированного дерева. Да Вы просто сорсы посмотрите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> разве нельзя сделать такое же и в бинарном дереве без маркировки

Теоретически - можно. Но это может занимать очень много времени. Для того, чтобы балансировка шла быстрей, и вводят специальные признаки.

И [красно-чёрные деревья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) - не единственный способ ускорить процесс. Есть ещё, например, [АВЛ-деревья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Одно из отличий (определяющее и другие характеристики) между к/ч и АВЛ состоит в том, что в к/ч на хранение этой дополнительной информации достаточно 1 бита (побитовая упаковка данных  может немного усложнять алгоритм, но здорово экономит память, что в некоторых случаях важно). А в АВЛ - целого (если не вдаваться в детали), что не так скромно, но позволяет производить балансировку чуть быстрей.

Сравнение других характеристик обоих типов деревьев по [этой ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.A1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.B1.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.BC_.D0.90.D0.92.D0.9B-.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BC).

Но по сути же и красно-чёрные, и АВЛ-деревья являются разновидностью двоичных деревьев.

Comment: [И еще одна](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_rbtree.aspx) хорошая ссылка (из той же статьи в вике, на которую ссылаетесь), рассказывает  про деревья поиска (в основном rb-tree)

Comment: Для меня наверное не понятна как происходит балансировка, чем помогает маркировка, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @JTan, см. комментарий avp к  ответу. Без доп. признаков пришлось бы перелопачивать всё дерево целиком при каждой операции балансировки. Что именно это за признаки и как они помогают - зависит от типа дерева, есть в статьях по ссылкам в ответе и комментах.